# Raspberry Pi with Arduino, Serial connection stops working

Tags: arduino-uno, serial

This is the hardware set-up at home,

Raspberry Pi GPIO -> Logic Level Converter -> Arduino -> Multiple Relays

[image]

I am running Raspbian and NodeJS on the Pi while the Arduino is loaded with StandardFirmata.
I connect NodeJS to the Arduino with the `johnny-five` package and it works well after it's started. But after extended periods, a few hours? The Arduino stops responding. Whatever command that I send to the Arduino won't be acted on. It's as though as the Arduino hung.
Both the Raspberry Pi and Arduino are being powered indenpendently with a 1A Nokia USB Adapter.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

1. [johnny-five](https://github.com/rwaldron/johnny-five)
2. [StandardFirmata](https://github.com/firmata/arduino/blob/master/examples/StandardFirmata/StandardFirmata.ino)
3. [NodeJS Server Code](https://gist.github.com/zanechua/f52a3d72946d7214f7cc)

Comment: Also, please add links to all the products you are using. I don't know what "Johnny-Five" is aside from a robot from an 80s movie. Same with "StandardFirmata".

Comment: Also, the details on the RPi code, as well as (ideally) pictures of how you have everything hooked up.

Comment: You might want to consider posting your code, otherwise every answer here will be a guess at best

Comment: Very often, if Arduino hangs, this is a memory problem (typically collision between the heap and the stack). It's gonna be hard to diagnose the actual issue without the source code of the program you downloaded to Arduino!

Comment: Hav you check that your Arduino still works properly with usual programs (blink in particular). You first need to find out if it is a hardware issue (pin or MCU fried due to too much current switched through the relays) or software.

Comment: Added links to all the software I am using and my NodeJS Server code. Will take pictures of the set-up in a bit.

Comment: @jfpoilpret added in connection. I'm sure the Uno is fine as I can just restart the uno and it starts working again. It's just that I'm trying to use it as a 24/7 solution

Comment: You have drawn a relay coild directly connected to pin 13, which is a very bad idea.  Use an NPN transistor to drive the relay, and give it a catch diode.

Comment: I've had a lot of serial hanging issues with my Arduino and Pi3. There seems to be a [lot of issues](https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/issues/88) with USB serial interfaces on the Pi. I've also noticed that my Pi seems to connect to the Arduino just fine after a reboot, but if I disconnect and then reconnect the Arduino (which should be fine), then it's able to connect initially, but the connect hangs after a few minutes.

Comment: A "1A" means 1 amp? I know the RPi 3 doesn't run reliably with less than 2.5 amps supplied by itself. Is it possible your power supply is overheating and dropping voltage?

Comment: @wilsotc Probably shouldn't be replying to a 4 year old thread. The Pi 3 didn't exist back in 2014. I was referring to a Original Raspberry Pi. Unless you're replying to Cerin.

Just so anyone finds this issue, I don't think I ever found a fix for it. It might be better now though.

Answer (score 1):

If none of the code is yours, and all code from the Firmata library, then the most possible cause that comes to mind after reviewing the library code is memory leak, which makes the next allocation to fail and by thus breaking the code.

The Firmata library does perform dynamic memory allocation, checkout Firmata.c, so it is realistic - I would suggest to take it with the Library's author.

Comment: Yeah. None of the code on the Arduino is mine. It's all Firmata's. So it's probably Firmata?

Comment: logically, it must be. Perhaps they didn't take into account running indefinitely.